# Configuring encrypted transmission in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found ways to configure symmetric encryption for the database user but no way to configure keys or something similar to encrypt the data sent to the database.

Is there any database supported by Ruby in Rails that allows specifying such encryption ? MariaDB / MySql is preferred.

With the help of tadman I found an adaptor which is able to set several SSL related parameters like sslkey but I still don't know how this works with database.yml: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.6/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter.html

Comment: MySQL generally can't deal with encrypted data in columns, it's opaque, so it can't be queried, indexed, or otherwise referenced between tables. You may want to look at encryption-at-rest instead using an encrypted drive volume to store your MySQL database.

Comment: @tadman I only need to encrypt the data on the network, not the database or rows

Comment: Then you need to set up SSL/TLS on your server and use that.

Comment: @tadman I know how to do this in Java, but found no setup for RoR. To me it seems this is not supported.

Comment: It's [in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.6/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter.html) so it appears to be supported.

Comment: Thanks @tadman, I obviously failed in finding the correct docs. Would you like to turn this in to an answer ? Otherwise I think I will just remove this redundant question ...

Comment: That's just a hint as to how it works. I'm not sure how this shakes out in terms of YML configuration, nor the implications of having to set up a certificate, but if you can get it working and describe it, I think a self-answer is warranted here.

Comment: @tadman I will not be able to provide this answer myself because I am no RoR developer. I just did some security research to find out what I can dem and from others ;-)